# Issues when installing Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Here is what I am getting:

[image]

So a long story short I had some problems with php while working on a ASP.net project and decided to reinstall everything. I may or may not have uninstalled something I shouldn't have but installing Apache, MySQL and php was no problem.

I have no idea what to do, I've restarted, downloaded again, checked windows updates and so on...

Here's the log:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 2014-07-22  11:14:38  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebPlatformInstaller.exe ===
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:538]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:538]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:538]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:540]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:540]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:546]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:546]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:554]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:569]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:569]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:571]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:571]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:571]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:572]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:657]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:657]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:660]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:667]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:667]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi has a digital signature
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:719]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:719]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:719]: Original package ==> C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:719]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\1fab7b.msi
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:721]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:722]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{7FE0FA51-E227-408B-BC5F-BC1A511B996D}'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:722]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:726]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:731]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:731]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:732]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:732]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:732]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:732]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{7FE0FA51-E227-408B-BC5F-BC1A511B996D}'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2014-07-22T11.14.37\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.txt'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Command Line: ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\Dan\Downloads CLIENTUILEVEL=3 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 CLIENTPROCESSID=5276 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{59DD335C-DB6B-4F5E-B4DE-7FDE8AD35E53}'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{7FE0FA51-E227-408B-BC5F-BC1A511B996D}'
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{7FE0FA51-E227-408B-BC5F-BC1A511B996D}'
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: Product {7FE0FA51-E227-408B-BC5F-BC1A511B996D} is not managed.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt not required, user is an admin
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:734]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: Package name extracted from package path: 'WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi'
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: Package to be registered: 'WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi'
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:735]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: Running product '{7FE0FA51-E227-408B-BC5F-BC1A511B996D}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REBOOT property. Its value is 'ReallySuppress'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Dan\Downloads'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '3'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '5276'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:737]: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:738]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its value is '53396ef08755ba48b7bd31fe642b860e'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:738]: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:738]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:738]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:740]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:741]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\Favorites
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:743]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:744]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\Documents
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:746]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:747]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:748]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:750]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:750]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:751]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:753]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\Pictures
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:755]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:756]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:757]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:758]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:759]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:761]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:763]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:764]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:765]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:766]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Dan\Desktop
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:767]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:767]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Windows\Fonts
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:767]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'Dan'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Installer\1fab7b.msi'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebToolsExtensionPublishingVWD2010_Only_1_3_BaseLocale\7CFB53AC7131C4817EEF67DF2800633004BF680C\WebPublishVWD2010Tools.msi'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI due to existing external or embedded UI
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI for service because it's not a quiet/basic install
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:771]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:772]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '2'.
=== Logging started: 2014-07-22  11:14:38 ===
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:772]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:772]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 11:14:38: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:773]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:773]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:773]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 11:14:38: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:775]: Doing action: AppSearch
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:775]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 11:14:38: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 11:14:38: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:776]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:776]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:776]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:776]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:777]: Note: 1: 1325 2: System.Web.dll 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:805]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding NETFRAMEWORK40FULLRTM property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:806]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MSIEXEC_DIR property. Its value is 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:806]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VWDEXPRESS_INSTALLDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:807]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VWDEXPRESS_SHELLDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:824]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VWDEXPRESS_PROJ_DIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ProjectTemplates\'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:825]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VWDEXPRESS_ITEM_DIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ItemTemplates\'.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:825]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:825]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:825]: Note: 1: 1325 2: VWDExpress.exe 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:826]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:826]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:826]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:826]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:827]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:827]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:828]: Note: 1: 1325 2: VWDExpress.exe 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:828]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:828]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:828]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:828]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:829]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:829]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:830]: Note: 1: 1325 2: VWDExpress.exe 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:830]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:830]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:830]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:830]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:831]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:831]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 11:14:38: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 11:14:38: LaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:833]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:833]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:833]: Product: Microsoft Web Publish - Visual Web Developer Express 2010 -- This product requires Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010. Please install Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010, then try installing this product again.

Action ended 11:14:38: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:14:38: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Product: Microsoft Web Publish - Visual Web Developer Express 2010 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:835]: Produkten installerades med Windows Installer. Produktnamn: Microsoft Web Publish - Visual Web Developer Express 2010. Produktversion: 1.3.40412.0. Produktspråk: 1033. Tillverkare: Microsoft Corporation. Slutförande- eller felstatus efter installationen: 1603.

MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:837]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (B8:DC) [11:14:38:837]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:839]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:839]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 2014-07-22  11:14:38 ===
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:840]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:840]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:840]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:840]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:840]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:841]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:841]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:841]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (B8:58) [11:14:38:841]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:842]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (9C:6C) [11:14:38:843]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2014-07-22  11:14:38 ===
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the good version ? x64 or x86 ? Try to install an other version like 2012 express ! I've installed visual studio on thress differents computers and i never had any problems.

Comment: x86 and I maybe should try that. But I've used 2010 on my other computer without a problem before so it's weird.